# Javascript/PHP ignore quotes in string

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I'm making a music player using php and javascript. I list the files like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
    $action = htmlspecialchars($_GET["action"]);

    if ($action == "listen") {
        function listFolderFiles($dir) {
            $ffs = scandir($dir);
            echo '<ol>';
            foreach($ffs as $ff){
                if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                    echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="changesong(\'' . $dir . '/' . $ff . '\');">'. $ff . '</a>';
                    if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $ff)) listFolderFiles($dir . '/' . $ff);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ol>';
        }

        listFolderFiles("music");
    }
} else {
    echo '<a href="?action=listen">> listen</a>';
}
?>
```

And I change the song like this:

```
<script>
function changesong(url) {
    $("#audioplayer").attr("src", url);
    $("#audioplayer").trigger('play');
 }
</script>
```

The problem is that songs with quotes in them won't play (for example Don't Stop Me Now). Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use addslashes(), like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="changesong(\'' .addslashes($dir . '/' . $ff). '\');">'. $ff . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape quotes for javascript function in HTML code like this:

Note that you probably need to escape double quotes as well, since they can interfere with HTML tag.

```
$link = $dir . '/' . $ff;
$link = str_replace("'", "&apos;", $link);
$link = str_replace('"', "&quot;", $link);
echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="changesong(\'' . $link . '\');">'. $ff . '</a>';
```